# Asp.Net ajax address control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I'm looking for  free asp.net ajax  control for address. It's something like 2 dropDowns for cities and countries and several textBoxes. Could anybody recommend anything?

Comment: *asp.net ajax control for address*. This could mean many things.

Comment: *dropDowns for cities and countries*, *several textBoxes*. This could mean many things. Try explaining what are your exact requirements.

Comment: You need a Control that contains some DropDownLists and some TextBoxes? You don't really mean that there is a such trivial control?
Create a UserControl, put these controls into it and call it `AddressControl`.